# spring.net transaction attribute works only for methods called from outside

Tags: transactions, aop, spring.net

In have a service class configured with Spring.NET.
DoWork accomplsihes two tasks which should run in two transactions. But Spring.NET seems not invoke any transactional AOP behaviour. I must annotate DoWork() with the Transaction attribute but this would wrap both Tasks in one transaction which I don't want.
How can I solve the problem?

```cs
IMyService service.DoWork();

public class MyServiceImpl : IMyService
{

public DoWork()
{
  Task1();
  Task2();
}

[Transaction(ReadOnly=false)]
protected void Task1()
{
  // do it
}

[Transaction(ReadOnly=false)]
protected void Task2()
{
  // do it
}
}
```

Comment: Related to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280143/asp-net-mvc-controller-declarative-aop-with-spring-net/4346791#4346791) I answered a month ago. A. 's answer is correct, and linked answer might give you some more background information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see [here](http://www.springframework.net/doc/reference/html/aop-quickstart.html), Spring.NET is using an interface-based dynamic proxying to accomplish its "AOP-ness". Interface based proxies work like [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). `Task1` and `Task2` methods are not parts of the interface, so Spring.NET can't decorate calls to these methods so it can't apply any behavior.

Changing `Task1` and `Task2` to public and adding it to the interface will not help either in your scenario, as `DoWork` calls `this.Task1()` and `this.Task2()`, where `this` will stand for concrete object, not an AOP proxy.

The only solution in your scenario is to use different AOP technique, either base class-based dynamic proxying at runtime (I don't know whether Spring.NET allows this, it can be done ie. with [Unity Interception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647107.aspx)) or compile-time weaving (like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp)).

Comment: It's a solution, but not the _only_ solution. Furthermore, it appears that spring.net supports an inheritance based proxy from version 1.3.1, which might help.

Answer (score 1):

A. is correct with his observation.

However, I would suggest extracting the two tasks in two separate classes, which are injected on a class that has the `DoWork()` routine.

```
public class MyServiceImpl : IMyService
{
  // use property injection to set Task1 and Task2
  public DoWork()
  {
    Task1.Process();
    Task2.Process();
  }

}

public class Task1
{
  [Transaction(ReadOnly=false)]
  protected void Process()
  {
    // do it
  }
}

public class Task2
{
  [Transaction(ReadOnly=false)]
  protected void Process()
  {
    // do it
  }
}
```