# Spring.NET AOP proxies and MS WebAPI controllers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, aop, spring.net

I am using MS WebAPI with Spring.NET for my DI, and making use of Sprint.NET AOP to mark methods as transactional.

When I mark a "Controller" action as transactional, I get the following error:

Unable to cast object of type 'CompositionAopProxy_13695853c76b40f8b9436e27afa947f0' to type 'TPMarketing.PayrollConsole.Web.Rest.Controllers.OrganisationsController'.","exceptionType":"System.InvalidCastException","stackTrace":" at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c_*DisplayClass13.b*_c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4()\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Does this mean you can't use proxy based AOP with Web API Controllers?

(I have got a workaround, I have made my own "Transaction" attribute for that inherits from ActionFilterAttribute to just use in the web tier)

thanks,
Jordan.

**EDIT...**
I haven't had time to check out Marijns suggestion below yet, so here is my workaround for anyone interested. This is the body of the code from my Action Filter: (TransactionManager is the Spring.NET IPlatformTransactionManager). I am still using the normal Spring.NET Transaction attribute in my service layer, and this should play nicely with that.

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        def.ReadOnly = ReadOnly;
        actionContext.Request.Properties[TRANSACTION_KEY] = TransactionManager.GetTransaction(def);
    }


    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        ITransactionStatus ts = actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties[TRANSACTION_KEY] as ITransactionStatus;
        if (ts.RollbackOnly || actionExecutedContext.Exception != null)
        {
            TransactionManager.Rollback(ts);
        }
        else
        {
            TransactionManager.Commit(ts);
        }
    }

    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280143/asp-net-mvc-controller-declarative-aop-with-spring-net/4346791#4346791

Comment: I haven't tried this with web api, but some time ago I've posted a [detailed this answer on this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9115510/322283), in the context of a "normal" asp.net MVC controller.

Comment: Ok will do, will probably be later in the week.

Answer (score 0):

CopositionAopProxy is based in contracts, is an implementation your interface, and cannot be cast to your class because is not a inheritance of your class, the proxy contains an instance of your class, as a property, but only implement same interfaces of your class.

Look at AOP [documentation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html):

> [**13.1.3. AOP Proxies in Spring.NET**](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html)
>
> Spring.NET generates AOP proxies at runtime using classes from the System.Reflection.Emit namespace to
>   create necessary IL code for the proxy class. This results in proxies
>   that are very efficient and do not impose any restrictions on the
>   inheritance hierarchy.
>
> Another common approach to AOP proxy implementation in .NET is to use
>   ContextBoundObject and the .NET remoting infrastructure as an
>   interception mechanism. We are not very fond of ContextBoundObject
>   approach because it requires classes that need to be proxied to
>   inherit from the ContextBoundObject either directly or indirectly. In
>   our opinion this an unnecessary restriction that influences how you
>   should design your object model and also excludes applying AOP to "3rd
>   party" classes that are not under your direct control. Context-bound
>   proxies are also an order of magnitude slower than IL-generated
>   proxies, due to the overhead of the context switching and .NET
>   remoting infrastructure.
>
> Spring.NET AOP proxies are also "smart" - in that because proxy
>   configuration is known during proxy generation, the generated proxy
>   can be optimized to invoke target methods via reflection only when
>   necessary (i.e. when there are advices applied to the target method).
>   In all other cases the target method will be called directly, thus
>   avoiding performance hit caused by the reflective invocation.
>
> Finally, Spring.NET AOP proxies will never return a raw reference to a
>   target object. Whenever a target method returns a raw reference to a
>   target object (i.e. "return this;"), AOP proxy will recognize what
>   happened and will replace the return value with a reference to itself
>   instead.
>
> The current implementation of the AOP proxy generator uses object
>   composition to delegate calls from the proxy to a target object,
>   similar to how you would implement a classic Decorator pattern. This
>   means that classes that need to be proxied have to implement one or
>   more interfaces, which is in our opinion not only a less-intruding
>   requirement than ContextBoundObject inheritance requirements, but also
>   a good practice that should be followed anyway for the service classes
>   that are most common targets for AOP proxies. **In a future release we
>   will implement proxies using inheritance, which will allow you to
>   proxy classes without interfaces as well and will remove some of the
>   remaining raw reference issues that cannot be solved using
>   composition-based proxies.**